# Unable to write Ordered Dict Results to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to write a simple program that imports a CSV file via pandas, does some geolocation using [this](https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder) module and writes the results to a new CSV file.

The module I am using returns a Dict that I should be able to split into diffrent columns but I cant seem to find any way of doing that.

A sample of the data I am working with:

```
ReportTime,ConvertedLat,ConvertedLong
2018-05-21 19:01:39.0000000,33.921127,-118.128477
2018-05-21 19:02:07.0000000,33.921125,-118.128454
2018-05-21 19:07:05.0000000,33.921274,-118.128355
2018-05-21 19:12:58.0000000,33.921248,-118.12841
2018-05-21 19:16:14.7281966,33.921248,-118.12841
2018-05-21 19:17:24.7289005,33.921248,-118.12841
2018-05-21 19:19:33.0000000,33.921268,-118.128418
2018-05-21 19:45:03.0000000,33.919818,-118.128749
2018-05-21 19:46:23.0000000,33.919817,-118.128748
2018-05-21 19:47:23.0000000,33.919754,-118.12907
2018-05-21 19:48:43.0000000,33.919703,-118.129382
2018-05-21 19:50:03.0000000,33.919585,-118.129189
2018-05-21 19:50:37.0000000,33.919383,-118.130163
2018-05-21 20:04:36.0000000,33.919789,-118.129882
2018-05-21 20:23:27.0000000,33.920036,-118.129822
2018-05-21 20:46:12.0000000,33.91993,-118.129499
2018-05-21 20:50:09.0062205,33.91993,-118.129499
2018-05-21 21:01:43.0000000,33.921195,-118.128403
2018-05-21 21:01:48.5683710,33.921195,-118.128403
2018-05-21 21:07:18.0000000,33.921135,-118.128448
2018-05-21 21:22:56.0000000,33.921089,-118.12849
2018-05-21 21:34:18.0000000,33.91897,-118.126026
2018-05-21 21:34:30.7203730,33.91897,-118.126026
2018-05-21 21:34:35.3922356,33.91897,-118.126026
2018-05-21 21:34:37.5172694,33.91897,-118.126026
2018-05-21 21:34:38.6891440,33.91897,-118.126026
2018-05-21 21:35:00.0000000,33.918843,-118.126122
2018-05-21 21:35:40.0000000,33.918683,-118.125967
2018-05-21 21:36:20.0000000,33.918748,-118.126087
2018-05-21 21:37:00.0000000,33.918762,-118.126094
2018-05-21 21:37:39.0000000,33.918776,-118.126102
2018-05-21 21:38:20.0000000,33.918772,-118.126098
2018-05-21 21:40:23.0000000,33.918516,-118.125526
2018-05-21 21:59:09.0000000,33.92636,-118.128706
```

And the code I have written:

```
import pandas as pd
import reverse_geocoder as rg
import csv

source = pd.read_csv("Lookup.csv") # source file location 

currentRow=0 # counts current row location

rowCount = source.shape[0] # queries number of rows

print(rowCount, "Rows total to be coded")


while currentRow < rowCount:


    currentLat = source.iloc[currentRow, 1] # stores the current working latitude

    currentLong = source.iloc[currentRow, 2] # stores the current working longitude

    currentReportedTime = source.iloc[currentRow, 0] # stores the current reported time

    Lat = currentLat 
    Long = currentLong

    coordinates = (Lat, Long)

    results = rg.search(coordinates,mode=1) # default mode = 2

    print(results)


    with open("results.csv", "a", newline='\n') as csv_file:
        csv_app = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_app.writerow([results, currentReportedTime])

    currentRow = currentRow + 1

else:
    print("Complete")
```

Any assistance would be most appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you use panda to read a csv file and csv to write. My solution would be to read the csv file and put the data in a list then call the rg.search(coordinates,mode=1) module and write out the csv again. See my snippet below. Of course this also depends on what the output format is of  rg.search(coordinates, mode=1). I have assumed result is a list or a tuple with 2 elements.

```
import csv

line_data = []
result = [0, 0]
with open('input.csv') as csvfile:
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    for row in csvdata:
        row[1] = float(row[1])
        row[2] = float(row[2])
        line_data.append(row)

for line in line_data:
    coordinates = (line[1], line[2])
    # now call your rg.search(coordinates, mode=1)
    # as I do not have this module I just make result the
    # same as line
    result[0], result[1] = line[1], line[2]

    print('date is {}, Lat is {}, Long is {}'.
          format(line[0], result[0], result[1]))

    with open('output.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        csvdata = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        csvdata.writerow([line[0], result[0], result[1]])
```

Comment: When I try doing this, I am unable to convert the string read in by the csv to a float.

Comment: Also when calling Type(), it appears to be a list but when I try to get the x item from the list, it appears to all be stored on the 1st item: 

`>>> type(results)
<class 'list'>
>>> results[0]
OrderedDict([('lat', '33.94001'), ('lon', '-118.13257'), ('name', 'Downey'), ('admin1', 'California'), ('admin2', 'Los Angeles County'), ('cc', 'US')])
>>> results[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: in reading the csvdata before appending the line_data do the conversion by adding the following 2 lines: row[1] = float(row[1]) and row[2] = float(row[2]

Comment: Looks like the float conversion is still failing:
`row[1] = float(row[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ConvertedLat`